# ionic component ts file is not working when I use the component in the home page

Tags: angular, ionic4

So I have added my ionic component to my ionic page. It displays, however all of my function on the component.ts file is not working?

here is my home html(this is were I would like to display my component):

```
<ion-content>
    <app-ion-col></app-ion-col>
</ion-content>
```

this is my component html:

```
<div class="ion-padding">
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col size="10">
            <h1>{{viewTitle}}</h1>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col size="2">
            <!-- Add event -->
            <ion-fab>
              <ion-fab-button size="small" (click)="openPopover($event)">
                <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
              </ion-fab-button>
            </ion-fab>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <!-- Move back one screen of the slides -->
          <ion-col size="4" text-left>
            <ion-button fill="clear" (click)="back()">
              <ion-icon name="arrow-back" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
          </ion-col>

          <!-- Move back to today -->
          <ion-col size="4">
            <ion-buttons class="todayBtn">
              <ion-button color="primary" expand="block" (click)="today()">Today</ion-button>
            </ion-buttons>                   
          </ion-col>

          <!-- Move forward one screen of the slides -->
          <ion-col size="4" text-right>
            <ion-button fill="clear" (click)="next()">
              <ion-icon name="arrow-forward" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
      <calendar 
        [eventSource]="eventSource" 
        [calendarMode]="calendar.mode" 
        [currentDate]="calendar.currentDate"
        (onEventSelected)="onEventSelected($event)"
        (onTitleChanged)="onViewTitleChanged($event)"
        (onTimeSelected)="onTimeSelected($event)" 
        startHour="6"
        endHour="20"
        step="30"
        startingDayWeek="1">
      </calendar>
</div>
```

component .ts (as you can see above I am using he selector):

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, Inject, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { CalendarComponent } from 'ionic2-calendar/calendar';
import { AlertController, PopoverController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';

import { AddEventComponent } from './add-event/add-event.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ion-col',
  templateUrl: './ion-col.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ion-col.component.scss'],
})
export class IonColComponent implements OnInit {

  event = {
    title: '',
    description: '',
    startTime: '',
    endTime: '',
    allDay: false
  };

  minDate = new Date().toISOString();

  calendar = {
    mode: 'month',
    currentDate: new Date()
  };

  viewTitle = 'view';

  @ViewChild(CalendarComponent) myCal: CalendarComponent;

// tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
  constructor(private alertCtrl: AlertController, @Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string, private popoverController: PopoverController) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myCal.loadEvents();
  }

  // changeMode(mode) {
  //   this.calendar.mode = mode;
  // }

  back() {
    const swiper = document.querySelector('.swiper-container') ['swiper'];
    swiper.slidePrev();
  }

  next() {
    const swiper = document.querySelector('.swiper-container') ['swiper'];
    swiper.slideNext();
  }

  today() {
    this.calendar.currentDate = new Date();
  }

  async onEventSelected(event) {
    const start = formatDate(event.startTime, 'medium', this.locale);
    const end = formatDate(event.endTime, 'medium', this.locale);

    const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
      header: event.title,
      subHeader: event.description,
      message: 'From: ' + start + '<br><br>To: ' + end,
    });
    alert.present();
  }

  onViewTitleChanged(title) {
    this.viewTitle = title;
  }

  onTimeSelected(ev) {
    const selected = new Date(ev.selectedTime);
    this.event.startTime = selected.toISOString();
    selected.setHours(selected.getHours() + 1);
    this.event.endTime = (selected.toISOString());
  }

  async openPopover(ev: Event) {
    const popover = await this.popoverController.create({
      component: AddEventComponent,
      event: ev,
      translucent: true
    });
    popover.present();
  }

  closePopover() {
    this.popoverController.dismiss();
  }


}
```

As explained the component html is displaying, it is when I try to click on any of my click functions that nothing seems to work.

It is however pulling and displaying data from the component.ts file through to the component.html and thus also displaying on the home.html

Comment: is there any error on your developer tools console?

Comment: @RezaRahmati No, there are no errors in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lied at the side menu. I added the side-menu under the shared folder and imported it. Thus placing everything behind the side-menu not allowing to click on any other element on the page

Answer (score 0):

This code here looks likely to be the problem:

```
  back() {
    const swiper = document.querySelector('.swiper-container') ['swiper'];
    swiper.slidePrev();
  }

  next() {
    const swiper = document.querySelector('.swiper-container') ['swiper'];
    swiper.slideNext();
  }
```

What is this `swiper-container`?

If it's an `ion-slide` somewhere else on the page then you are probably unable to "see" it.

Ionic 4 uses web components and they are encapsulated. You cannot just use traditional techniques to grab at bits of the page as they are hidden from the outside world. This is so the web component can operate without being broken by some other conflicting web component on the page.

I think what you are going to need is an `@Output` event.

The theory is that you `emit` an event (a back event for example) from this component, and then a parent component can subscribe to that event and do something, like move the slider where it has access to the slider.

You have used this before many times without realising it. That's what the `(click)` of your `<ion-button fill="clear" (click)="next()">` is for example. Inside the web component, the button is clicked. It emits the click event and then your code outside runs the `next()` to process this click.

If this isn't enough to solve your problem please can you give some more idea of the `swiper-container` and I'll try to write some code for you.